# Get ABRecordRef from ABNewPersonViewController's Overridden Done Button Tap

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a class that inherits from `ABNewPersonViewController`, and I have overridden the method that is called when the `Done` button is tapped. My question is, how do I get access to the `ABRecordRef` in my custom method? Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(SaveMember)];
}



- (void)SaveMember
{
    NSString *firstName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(/*???? - This is where the ABRecordRef should go*/, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What is `ABRecordRef`? Where is it stored?

Comment: If I did not override the done button, the default delegate method that is called is: - (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person. That includes the ABRecordRef parameter with the person's details. That's what I need access to in my method.